# Filter array inside array of object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, nested

I have a table with data and filter, filter is array of selected options, now I want to create a new array with tabledata which event.type exist in filter array for example:

if filter array is looking like this:
levels = ['Beginner', 'Medium']
now it should return all table data events which level has both values

```html
const scheduleData = [
    {
        weekDay: {
            title: 'Day 1',
            day: 'Monday',
            date: 'November 1',
        },
        events: [
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: "React 18 / Next 11 - What's  new?",
                level: 'Beginner, Medium',
                desc: 'Sit lulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                time: '15:30h-16:30h',
                duration: '1h',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsd',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
            },
            {
                icon: '',
                type: 'Pause',
                typeColor: typeColor.Pause,
                title: 'Take a 30 minutes break!',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Mental breaks increase productivity, replenish attention, solidify memories and encourage creativity.',
                time: '16:30h-17:00h',
                duration: '30m',
                lecturer: '1',
                lecturerImg: '',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/Lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'React frameworks comparison',
                level: 'Beginner, Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat, nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '17:00h-18:00h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
            {
                icon: '',
                type: 'Pause',
                typeColor: typeColor.Pause,
                title: 'Take a 30 minutes break!',
                level: 'Beginner, Medium',
                desc: 'Mental breaks increase productivity, replenish attention, solidify memories and encourage creativity.',
                time: '18:00h-18:30h',
                duration: '',
                lecturer: '2',
                lecturerImg: '',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/Lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'ES2021 / TS, Ecosystem and more',
                level: 'Beginner',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id. Consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdfsd',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '18:30h-19:30h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        weekDay: {
            title: 'Day 2',
            day: 'Tuesday',
            date: 'November 2',
        },
        events: [
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'React Architecture for most of your projects',
                level: 'Beginner',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi, mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdssdfsd',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '9:00h-10:00h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'React State Management alternatives ',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollity officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: 'TBA',
                duration: 'TBA',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'Scalable React Architecture',
                level: 'Medium, Advanced',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunte exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdfsdfsc',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '17:00h-18:00h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        weekDay: {
            title: 'Day 3',
            day: 'Wednesday',
            date: 'November 3',
        },
        events: [
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/class.svg',
                type: 'Master Class',
                typeColor: typeColor.Class,
                title: 'React Server Components',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecati. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'dsfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '9:30h-10:30h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'Client Side vs. Server Side Rendering and Data Fetching',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostruda ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'dsfsdfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '15:30h-16:30h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
            {
                icon: '',
                type: 'Pause',
                typeColor: typeColor.Pause,
                title: 'Take a 30 minutes break!',
                level: 'Beginner, Medium',
                desc: 'Mental breaks increase productivity, replenish attention, solidify memories and encourage creativity.',
                time: '16:30h-17:00h',
                duration: '30m',
                lecturer: '3',
                lecturerImg: '',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'Backend for Frontend (BFF)',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniamt incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '17:00h-18:00h',
                duration: '1h',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        weekDay: {
            title: 'Day 4',
            day: 'Thursday',
            date: 'November 4',
        },
        events: [
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/class.svg',
                type: 'Master Class',
                typeColor: typeColor.Class,
                title: 'Serverless React',
                level: 'Medium',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quist. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'dfssdfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '9:00h-11:30h',
                duration: '2,5h',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/class.svg',
                type: 'Master Class',
                typeColor: typeColor.Class,
                title: 'React and GraphQL',
                level: 'Beginner',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamcos deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdfc',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: '15:30h-17:30h',
                duration: '2h',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        weekDay: {
            title: 'Day 5',
            day: 'Monday',
            date: 'November 5',
        },
        events: [
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'TBA',
                level: 'TBA',
                desc: 'Hit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfdsf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: 'TBA',
                duration: 'TBA',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/lecture.svg',
                type: 'Lecture',
                typeColor: typeColor.Lecture,
                title: 'TBA',
                level: 'TBA',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrude ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fdsfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: 'TBA',
                duration: 'TBA',
            },
            {
                icon: '/images/icons/workshop.svg',
                type: 'Workshop',
                typeColor: typeColor.Workshop,
                title: 'TBA',
                level: 'TBA',
                desc: 'Sit nulla est ex deserunte exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat.',
                lecturer: 'fsdfsdf',
                lecturerImg: R.images.marko,
                time: 'TBA',
                duration: 'TBA',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

This is how I tried to do it,
but its working only for first option after that it return empty array...

```js
const { types, levels } = useFilter()
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredData(data)
        if (types.length !== 0 {
            setFilteredData(filterDataByType)
            
        }
    }, [types])

    const filterDataByType = () => {
        return filteredData.map((day) => {
            return {
                ...day,
                events: day.events.filter((event: any) => types.indexOf(event.type) > -1),
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Try this for first: `day.events.filter((event: any) => types.includes(event.type))`